# How to insert Laravel Project into Apache Tomcat servelet?

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, laravel

I am new to web development and I am stuck on how to insert my project into Apache Tomcat. Before I created a simple website and inserted my code into the web apps folder and routed the url to that location. I tried the same thing with laravel and routed to public/index.php and all that shows up is the file index.php it doesn't pull up my site.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code that you have got and be more specific on the issue you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question -- all your words makes sense but the order you've put them in does not.  Apache Tomcat is for running Java applications.  Laravel is a PHP framework.  PHP web applications work by using the Apache web server, or a fast CGI implementation in other web server light nginx.  They have nothing to do with Tomcat.

Setup apache to treat your Laravel `public` folder as a document root, and configure apache to sue mod_rewrite and .htaccess files.  That's the basic Laravel (and PHP) setup.